# Good Windows 7 IDE for node.js devlopment over SSH

Tags: node.js, windows-7, ide

Just starting to learn linux and I have an Amazon EC2 server running Ubuntu 11.10.  I'm trying to learn node.js and get a simple game server up and running.  My home machine is Windows 7 so I'm using PuTTy to SSH into my EC2 server.  I was wondering what IDE would you guys recommend?

- I like NetBeans a lot and this is my preferred IDE for php, but there is no node.js project type and little support via plugins.
- I'm not a big fan of Eclipse since it seems more complicated than it needs to be - but if that's the best I'll use it - currently I have Eclipse for PHP Developers (Helios) and Indigo - which would be best?  Do the versions really matter?

Answer (score 2):

Intellij IDEA is always worth a look.  It is my personal favorite.

Comment: Sorry Sethcall, you bet me to it - double answer for essentially the same IDE speaks volumes though.

Comment: Will the community version be adequate?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm is a paired down version of InteliJ that focusses just on Javascript rather than Java, went through a dozen IDE's and text editors until I came across it - integrates with the Node server to enable breakpoints, debugging, etc. Only $49 for a personal version.

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: I should add that you should get Version 4 which is currently in Beta as it has much better Node support. Seriously this IDE has revolutionised my Javascript development. Has Zen coding, JsLint, JsHint, JSDoc and CoffeeScript support plus plenty of others. If you use something like closure compiler or a minifier you can create a build script, or like me make a macro that saves all files and builds your project.

Comment: Just FYI - Sublime Text 2 has all of these features as well if you're looking for a lighter editing environment.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).  It has a lot of great plug-ins for Javascript (JSLint one is a must have) and I find that it stays out of the way when I'm just trying to get work done. It's also multi-platform so you can have a consistent editing environment across all of your machines.

Comment: Doesn't really feel much like a full featured IDE.  I'm not sure this will offer much over an app like Komodo Edit and/or NotePad++.

Comment: That's where all the great plug-ins come in. You can check out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/essential-sublime-text-2-plugins-and-extensions/ for some of the more essential ones. The go anywhere function is pretty awesome as well.

Comment: How's the debugging support for Node.js in Sublime Text 2? Can I step through a program within the editor? Breakpoints? The website doesn't mention debugging, which would classify it as a powerful editor, rather than as an IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft WebMatrix a tool from Microsoft. You can find further details @ http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: Too short an answer. Give more detail.